# Firebase observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged callback never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to to get real time updated database object. Whenever a new message added in chat list.

If I Use

```
observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
```

it works and respond well. But ofcourse it will give me results once.

If I call the below method:

```
observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged
```

as of my knowledge It will give results first time and every time when the child is changed. (new message added)

but this never called back. Not first time not if I add some new message in database.

This is how I m calling these methods:

In my.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
[self getChats];
```

and finally:

```
-(void) getChats {

//  this is working
[[[_ref child:@"chat_rooms"] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);

}];

// this is not working / Never calling
[[[_ref child:@"chat_rooms"] child:userID] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged
 withBlock:^ (FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

     NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
     NSLog(@"%@",dict);

 }];


 // this is not working / Never calling too
[[[_ref child:@"chat_rooms"] child:userID] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded
 withBlock:^ (FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

     NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
     NSLog(@"%@",dict);

 }];

}

//this is how I m sending message to database. 
//and this is working good. message added in node. verified at firebase console
- (void)sendMessage : (NSDictionary*) dict
{
    [[[[_ref child:@"chat_rooms"] child:userID] childByAutoId] setValue:dict];
}
```

Guide me where I m wrong, OR what should I have to use to get (real time) updated chats.

Comment: Instead of ChildChanged use childAdded in Observer.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have update the question. It is not working

Comment: how you checking whether the func is calling or not?

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have placed breakpoint and you can see the NSLog statement. that are never print.

Comment: I mean from UI end what you are doing in your app to take callback. Bcz i am also using Firebase (swift) and working perfect.

Comment: Nothing at this moment. Just trying to get the updated results. After that I will call `[collectionView reloadData]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146483/discussion-between-dahiya-boy-and-m-zubair-shamshad).

Comment: Are you actually changing or adding a child in the node : chat_rooms in your database ?

Comment: @ArpitJain yes of course, Adding value in node chat_room

Comment: Please show code how you are adding or changing value in node chat_room

Comment: @ArpitJain shouldn't it call even at first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Figured out the solution,

For the first time If we don't have the **Child Node** created under firebase database. In my case it is `chat_room` with `userID`

So the observer `observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged` will never called because observer did not find which child it has to observe. And I guess it is not even registered to observe.

So when I have added first message in `chat_room`. Node is created for that user. Then I have to get all the records with `observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue`

Then registered the Child Changed observer and finally on every change `observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged` is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initializing your FIRDatabaseReference each time you are adding an observer. So try as follows : 
In `viewDidLoad` method,

```
_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
_ref = [[_ref child:@"chat_rooms"] child:userID]; // Pass Your userID here
```

Then, call your observer as,

```
[_ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded
 withBlock:^ (FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

     NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
     NSLog(@"%@",dict);

}];
```

Hope, it works

Answer (score 0):

You’re totally wrong, if you want to get the realtime value of an object you may wanted to use `FIRDataEventTypeAdded` on the type of Firebase database reference

Comment: Okay but: This is not calling back. 
I have tried this too. Same Issue